# how to have multiple $http call inside of a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xmlhttprequest

i tried to retrieve two data, one from the API and from my json, when i make the call i receive just the second call on my view.

json 1

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "img":"images/clientlogos/21747.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "img": "images/clientlogos/FMI.png"
        }
]
```

jason @ from APi call

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Enough",
        "forecasted": 22,
        "budget": 40,
        "hoursspent": 3.53999997675419,
        "currentcosts": 965.393393660635,
        "xerototal": 2800
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Fad Ltd",
        "forecasted": 96.5,
        "budget": 300,
        "hoursspent": 199.91000029631,
        "currentcosts": 66234.589716303,
        "xerototal": 176472
    },
]
```

my factory

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http){
  return{
client: function(callback){
        $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://www.outleading.co.za/api/api/clientdashboarddata",
          cache:true
        }).then(callback);
    },  
list: function(callback){
        $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: "data/Client.json",
          cache:true
        }).then(callback);
    } 
  };
});
```

my controller

```
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, myFactory) {
      myFactory.client(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.myClients = data;
      })
      myFactory.list(function(response){
        var data= response.data;
        $scope.myClients= data;
      })
        };
      }
    })
```

my html

inside my ng-repeat i want to get{{client.img}} from my json and {{client.clientname}} from the api call

```
<div class="card client-card" ng-repeat="client in myClients>
                <div class="client-logo">
                     <img ng-src="{{client.img}}" alt="{{client.name}}">
                </div>
        </div>
```

so Any help will be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify factory to return promise it gives you flexibility

```
app.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        client: function () {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://www.outleading.co.za/api/api/clientdashboarddata",
                cache: true
            });
        },
        list: function () {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "data/Client.json",
                cache: true
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) and wait for all promises to complete

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, myFactory, $q) {
    $q.qll(myFactory.client(), myFactory.list()).then(function (result) {
        $scope.myClients = result[0].data;
        var images = result[1].data;

        $scope.myClients.forEach(function(client){
            // find index of image for client
            var idx= images.findIndex(function(x){
                return x.id == client.id
            });

            client.name = images[idx].name; 
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @satpal it work, but not in the way i was expecting, in fact now it just dupplicate both json.

Comment: base on the Id of each json, i want to repeat the image of the first json and the clientname of the second json

Comment: their is no name on the first json, it a mistake, the first json contain the images and the second json contain the name, i want to link the two, in one single ng repeat

Comment: thanks @stapal but is not working, try to see your code is a small mistake in line $scope.myClients.forEach(function, you mispelled n,  their is not another way to acheive it, a simple way

Answer (score 0):

You are calling two APIs and overriding the input.

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, myFactory) {
      myFactory.client(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.myClients = data;  //Same variable 
      })
      myFactory.list(function(response){
        var data= response.data;
        $scope.myClients= data; //Same variable 
      })
        };
      }
    })
```

Instead of saving data in $scope.myClients in both the calls, use some different variable name. I guess second one should be $scope.lists

Comment: sure, but i want to repeat both data inside of a ng-repeat, if the second one is $scope.list is not gonna be display on my repeat, my ng-repeat is: client in myClients